# why do we need to use (void*)&a instead of &a

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int a;
  int* b;
  a = 40;
  b = &a;
  printf("the address of a is %p, and the value of a is %d \n",&a, a);
  return 0;
}
```

I find that both `(void*)&a` and `&a` print the same thing. So why do people still add `(void*)`? Is it just a habit?

Comment: I was actually wondering why GCC gives a warning about this too. I find nothing in the standard about va_list requiring `void*` specifically, see 7.16.1. Sure fprintf states that `%p` should have a pointer to void, but pointer to void is compatible with every pointer type anyhow. So it seems that GCC is overly picky.

Comment: @Lundin The requirement that a `void*` is passed for `%p` is found in the documentation for `printf`, not in the description of `va_list`.

Comment: In practice it might not matter (for typical x86_64), because the generated code would be the same. In principle, some very weird C implementations might make a difference. Twenty years ago, on Cray, `char*` & `double*` had *different* sizes.

Comment: `why do we need to use (void*)&a instead of &a` because of the `printf` function and because of `GCC` which knows that too, it asking you to use it.    Any way `GCC-5.2` doesn't complains anymore.

Comment: @Lundin pointer to void is NOT compatible with 'every' pointer type. Any *data* pointer (object or incomplete in C90 and C99, object including incomplete in C11) can be *converted to and from* pointer to void, but that does NOT make them compatible and does NOT mean they have the same representation or even size.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah, I came to that conclusion too after reading up on this further. Turned out that the standard definition of compatible is not the same as implicitly convertible. Still it makes no sense to have pointers of different size for the same platform, that's just nonsense. All unorthodox systems that have extended memory etc use non-standard extensions to deal with that (for example near and far pointers). So as usual, the C standard continues the spirit of "must be portable to computers that will never exist".

Answer (score 5):

You use specifier `%p` to print address stored in pointer, and this format specifier expects type to be `void *` .  And as `&a` is of type `int *` , cast `void *` is used .

Answer (score 2):

The `printf()` format specifier `%p` expects a `void*` type pointer. Since what you are passing might not be a `void*` type pointer, and the standard does not mandate for all pointers to have the same format, is is important that you cast a pointer to `void*` before passing it to printf.

For instance:

```
int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
printf("a is %p",(void*)a);
```

Is done as best practice incase `int*` and `void*` are not similar

Comment: @PascalCuoq Now It does.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I need a coffee. __should__ be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

C Standard says that using an incorrect specifier for an argument in printf will result in undefined behavior.

> 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function
>
> 9. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. 282) If any argument is
>    not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>    undefined.

Since *pointer to int* is not the same type as *pointer to void*, and `%p` may only be used for a *pointer to void* and even if some other rules says that any pointer may be converted to *pointer to void* and back, that doesn't change the fact that the behavior is undefined, because of the quoted rule.

Comment: fprintf says that the `%p` expects a pointer to void, and then in the section about va_list in the standard (7.16.1.1) says `"...if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined,..."`. But `int*` is compatible with `void*` so it is well-defined behavior. Imo the section about va_lists is the relevant one. I think the note about fprintf UB is rather related to using fprintf `%d` format specifier but passing a `bananas_t`, it is on a higher application level.

Comment: @Lundin The quote relates to all specifiers not just to %d. I don't know what you meant for the rest of the comment.

Comment: I mean that the text regarding va_list specifies what makes a "correct type" on a lower level. Otherwise this would be undefined behavior too: `int a=0; printf("%u", a);` The reason why this is not UB is the text in 7.16.1.1.

Comment: @Lundin One could argue that that printf is undefined behavior. For example: The specifier is simply not correct as far as 7.21 is concerned. I don't see why would compatibility even matter in this case, it certainly isn't mention anywhere in the chapter, and specifiers don't care about compatibility of va_arg. Anyway, I saw some discussions in comments last year, and I didn't find the matter resolved. Maybe you could ask a question about it, but it will probably be ignored or misinterpreted. Perhaps a large bounty will be required at some point to get the attention and get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, different pointer types are not necessarily interchangable.

Secondly, for varargs no implicit conversion takes place as the compiler does not know the expected type.